# How to update model field using django signals when updating object in m2m field?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, signals

I'm trying to update the order total on updating quantity on OrderItem. For that i'm using django signal m2m change with post_add or post_remove action. Here's my model:

```py
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)


class Order(models.Model):
    order_item = models.ManyToManyField('OrderItem')
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)
```

**OrderItem total update signal**

```py
def pre_save_order_tem_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    """Receiver for updating total of OrderItem"""
    total = instance.item.price * instance.quantity
    instance.total = total


pre_save.connect(pre_save_order_tem_receiver, sender=OrderItem)
```

**m2m changes signal**

```
def m2m_changed_order_item_receiver(sender, instance, action, *args, **kwargs):
    """Receiver for updating total of Order through OrderItem"""
    if action in ["post_add", "post_remove"]:
        order_items = instance.order_item.all()
        total = 0
        for order_item in order_items:
            total += order_item.item.price * order_item.quantity
        instance.total = total
        instance.save()


m2m_changed.connect(m2m_changed_order_item_receiver, sender=Order.order_item.through)
```

**Testcase:**

```
    def test_updating_order_item_quantity_in_order(self):
        order_item1, order_item1_data = create_sample_order_item(
            item=self.item1,
            quantity=2,
            data_only=False
        )

        order_item2, order_item2_data = create_sample_order_item(
            item=self.item2,
            quantity=2,
            data_only=False
        )

        order, _ = create_sample_order(
            order_items=[order_item1_data, order_item2_data],
            data_only=False
        )

        order_items = order.order_item.all()

        for order_item in order_items:
            if order_item == order_item2:
                order_item2.quantity = 10
                order_item2.save()
        order.save()

        # update
        order_item2_total = order_item2.item.price * 10

        # works completly fine but i'm searching for alternative method using signal
        # order.order_item.remove(order_item2)
        # order.order_item.add(order_item2)

        order.refresh_from_db()
        order_item1.refresh_from_db()
        order_item2.refresh_from_db()

        # check weather OrderItem total is updated or not
        self.assertEqual(order_item2.total, order_item2_total)

        # fails here
        self.assertEqual(order.total, order_item1.total + order_item2.total)
```

It works completly fine when i first remove the OrderItem object from Order, update and add it. i.e

```py
# remove order_item
order.order_item.remove(order_item2)

# perform update 
order_item.total = ......

# add back
order.order_item.add(order_item2)
```

Is there any other reliable method other than removing, updating and adding using signal??

**UPDATED:**

According to clue provided by [Muhammad Ihfazhillah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61512914/10901575) i've achieved partially working code, which only works from admin panel.

```py
def listen_order_item_change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    orders = instance.order_set.all()
    for order in orders:
        # get all order items
        order_items = order.order_item.all()

        total = 0
        # find total for order
        for order_item in order_items:
            total += order_item.total
        order.total = total

        # save order
        order.save()
    # instance.save() -> causes RecursionError

post_save.connect(listen_order_item_change, sender=OrderItem)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to listen for `post_save` signal to do this because you updating the individual object.

The `m2m_changed`'s `post_add` and `post_remove` signals only dispatched when there is something added into model relation or removed.

Here is the snippet for using `post_save` on OrderItem instance.

```
def listen_order_item_change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # get all orders
    orders = instance.order_set.all()
    for order in orders:
        # update the each total for each order here

post_save.connect(listen_order_item_change, sender=OrderItem)
```

Comment: don't forget to save the order instance in for loop block

Answer (score -1):

I think this can be achieved by simply triggering `post_save` signal.

First of all what you can do is, add a method inside the `OrderItem` model for updating the total which can be called later from `post_save` signal reciever.

Here is the snippet for update method that is to be defined inside `OrderItem` model.

```
  def update_total_price(self):
        """for updating the total_price of an ordered item"""
        quantity = Decimal(self.quantity)
        unit_price = self.item.price #for getting the unit price of the item
        new_total_price = quantity * unit_price
        self.total = new_total_price
        self.save()
        return new_total_price
```

And finally the snippet for using post_save signal along with its reciever can be

```
def post_save_orderitem_total_receiver(sender,instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.update_total_price()

post_save.connect(post_save_orderitem_total_receiver, sender=OrderItem)
```

Comment: It instead updates total of order item which is not the purpose of what i'm asking.